# Start a chromedriver session using w3c webdriver api

Tags: json, rest, selenium-chromedriver, w3c, web-testing

I'm trying to start a Chromium session using the chromedriver and w3c webdriver API, I send a POST request to `http://localhost:9515/session` with the body

```
{
    "capabilities": {
        "alwaysMatch": {
            "platformName": "linux",
            "chrome:browserOptions": {
                "binary": "/usr/bin/chromium",
                "args": ["--start-page=about:blank"]
            }
        },
        "firstMatch": [
            {"browserName": "chrome"}
        ]
    }
}
```

And i get the next response

```
{
    "sessionId": "b1a413df152017cd223dbabbcf1d2ffe",
    "status": 33,
    "value": {
        "message": "session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.14.47-1-MANJARO x86_64)"
    }
}
```

Which capabilities are missing or invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chromedriver (as of version 2.41 at least) simply does not support the W3C WebDriver API.

The missing capability required by chromedriver is `capabilities.alwaysMatch.goog:chromeOptions.w3c: true`, i.e.

{ "capabilities" : { "alwaysMatch" : { "goog:chromeOptions" : { "w3c" : true } } } }

This is a deficiency in chromedriver. If you want to experiment with the W3C WebDriver protocol, you can use `geckodriver` (firefox), which has near-perfect support for the W3C WebDriver API.

Comment: Also see https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/chromedriver_status.md for WebDriver command support in Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Java code:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("w3c", true);
    new ChromeDriver(options);
```